# Keys for klepto dir_archive?

Tags: klepto

I've created a klepto dir_archive.

On subsequent archive access, how can the archive keys be determined without loading the entire archive into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> import klepto as kl
>>> kl.archives.dir_archive()
dir_archive('memo', {}, cached=True)
>>> d = _
>>> d['a'] = 0
>>> d['b'] = 1
>>> d['c'] = 2
>>> d
dir_archive('memo', {'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}, cached=True)
>>> d.dump()
>>>
```

Then restart the session...

```
>>> import klepto as kl
>>> d = kl.archives.dir_archive()
>>> d
dir_archive('memo', {}, cached=True)
>>> d.archive.keys()
['a', 'c', 'b']
```

There are also several private methods, if you'd need something peculiar:

```
>>> d.archive._keydict()
{'a': None, 'c': None, 'b': None}
```

But, the main point is: you can easily interact with the `dir_archive` without loading it, by using the `archive` attribute.